# How do I install decNumber?

Tags: linux, gcc

This application is part of gcc but I'm trying to upgrade just decNumber. Is this even possible?

I svn checked out the source for decNumber from gcc's website. When I run ./configure within the libdecnumber directory, I get this error:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `autoreconf -i -f`, maybe?

Comment: My version of autoconf is out of date. any other routes?